# Problem with TikZ - can't find file 'tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex'

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I've downloaded all the appropriate packages (tikz/pgf).
I tried to compile the following code but I get the message :
`I can't find file 'tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex'`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
  {} & A \arrow{d}{i} \arrow[dashed,swap]{dl}{\exists \tilde{\varphi}} \\
  B \arrow{r}{\varphi} & C
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

What do you recommend me to do?

Edit:
Now again I try another code which doesn't seem to work (I have checked marked all the boxes in the update manager):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
$$
\begin{tikzcd}
X \arrow[r, hook, "x \mapsto (x,1)"] \arrow[dr, "f"]
& Cyl f \arrow[d, "(x,t)\mapsto (x,0)"]\\
& Y
\end{tikzcd}
$$
\end{document}
```

I also tried without the dollars signs but in vein.
Can you see what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Are you sure everything is installed properly? I don't have any problems. It might be the case that you still have TikZ 2.10 where current version is 3.00. You can put `\listfiles` in the preamble and read the log file for version information.

Comment: There are a lot of complicated package dependencies that can be very hard to predict; it's best to use your dedicated updating/installation tool. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) for details, which include screenshots

Comment: What is the preamble?

Comment: You were right, I needed to update my packages. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been resolved by updating the TeX distribution

Comment: What is the specific problem that you're getting? Is it still a missing package/code? Perhaps you need `$x \mapsto (x,1)$` rather than the surrounding `$$`...`$$`.

Comment: @Alan The 'preamble' is everything from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}`, but nothing after.